# Can a blink dog take items with them when using their Dimension Door ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Blink dogs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/blink-dog) have "quickened Dimension Door (self only)" as an at-will spell-like ability. I am having some trouble determining exactly what the "self only" restriction entails in this case. It clearly intends to forbid the blink dog bringing along other creatures. It looks to me like, by RAW, it would also forbid them bringing along inanimate items, but this is somewhat less clear.

Can a blink dog carry a non-creature object with them when using Dimension Door? RAW answers are preferred, but any references providing insight into the RAI would also be useful.

Comment: What about getting crazy like does a zombie count? A vampire? A flesh to stone statue? A golem? Heh.

Comment: @ZanLynx None of those really add anything new to the situation. The zombie, vampire, and golem are all creatures, so unambiguously cannot be taken along. The F2S statue is an inanimate object, not a creature, despite what its made of and any reversibility that making process might have, so it would be takable or not, as per the question's answer, the same as a saddle bags or a dagger held in the dog's teeth, or any other inanimate object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### A [blink dog](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/blink-dog) using [*dimension door*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) can take objects

*Self only* means the blink dog can target only itself, not other creatures, but objects the blink dog's attending when it uses its *dimension door* ability travel with it (up to the blink dog's maximum load; see below).

The part of [*dimension door*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door)'s description that applies:

> You instantly transfer yourself from your current location to any other spot within range. You always arrive at exactly the spot desired - whether by simply visualizing the area or by stating direction. After using this spell, you can't take any other actions until your next turn. **You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn't exceed your maximum load.**

The part of [*dimension door*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door)'s description that doesn't apply:

> You may also bring one additional willing Medium or smaller creature (carrying gear or objects up to its maximum load) or its equivalent per three caster levels. A Large creature counts as two Medium creatures, a Huge creature counts as two Large creatures, and so forth. All creatures to be transported must be in contact with one another, and at least one of those creatures must be in contact with you.